# Find occurrences of string on array - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, grep

I need to find occurrences of a string on an array on the client side.
The examples on the [JQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) all use number comparisons, for some reason.

Basically I'm trying to do what in the Terminal is as easy as `grep pattern < file.txt`, but have the data come from an array instead of a file.

This is my code so far. Won't be much help but it'll give you an idea of how I try to accomplish this.

```
var array = [
'item 1 shalala',
'this is other item',
'more examples',
'dontknowwhatelsetosay',
'wildcard'
];

$( "#submit" ).keydown(function( event ) {
    //console.log( "Handler for .keydown() called." );
    var result = $.grep(array, function(value, i){
        // No idea what to do.
        // Will write the array elements that contain the pattern on a div using $('#divId').text(results);
    });
});
```

I usually work on lower level languages, I hope the answer is not too obvious.
EDIT: #submit is on an input text field.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for GREP? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/ That shows you need a return with a truthy check based on the string in the input. Do you know how to get the value entered by the user? Do you know how to determine if a string exists in another?

Comment: Obviously did. Don't you see I linked it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`indexOf()` will search for a substring in a string, it returns its position when found, or `-1` when not found.

```
var result = $.grep(array, function(value) {
    return value.indexOf(pattern) != -1;
}
```